# Wordpress Pagination is not working anymore in my custom page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have this custom post overview "blog" for all posts of native wordpress system. Everything is working good so far but pagination is not working. I really don't understand why it is not working. Can you help me?

```
 <?php

        //adhere to paging rules
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
            $paged = get_query_var('paged');
        } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { // applies when this page template is used as a static homepage in WP3+
            $paged = get_query_var('page');
        } else {
            $paged = 1;
        }
        echo("$paged " . $paged);

        $posts_per_page = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'number_of_items',true);
        if (!$posts_per_page) {
            $posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');
        }

        echo("$posts_per_page " . $posts_per_page);

        global $query_string;
            $args = array(
                'numberposts'     => '',
                'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
                'offset'          => 0,
                'cat'        =>  '',
                'orderby'         => 'date',
                'order'           => 'DESC',
                'include'         => '',
                'exclude'         => '',
                'meta_key'        => '',
                'meta_value'      => '',
                'post_type'       => 'post',
                'post_mime_type'  => '',
                'post_parent'     => '',
                'paged'             => $paged,
                'post_status'     => 'publish'
            );
        query_posts( $args );
        ?>

        <div class="container page-content blog">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>

                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                       <h1 style=" background-color: white; padding: 1%; padding-left: 16%; "> Unsere Referenzen / verkaufte Objekte:</h1>
                    <?php
                    if ( have_posts() ) :
                    // Start the Loop.
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>

                    <div style="padding: 5%; padding-left: 18%; padding-bottom: 0%; " id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class("box-container"); ?>>

                    <?php the_title( '<h2 style="font-size: 22px !Important" class="post-title">' ); ?>
                    </h2>

                    <h2 style="font-size: 20px !Important"> 
                    VERKAUFT
                    </h2>


                        <?php realto_post_thumbnail();?>    

        <?php  if($post->post_content != "") {echo"<h2 style='font-size: 22px !Important; padding-top:30px;' class='post-title'> Kundenrezension: </h2>";} ?>
                        <div style="padding-top:10px; padding-left:0px;" class="padding30">

                            <?php /*the_excerpt();*/ the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    endwhile;
                        // Previous/next post navigation.
                        nt_pagination();
                        wp_reset_query();
                    else :
                        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                        get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

                    endif;
                    ?>
                </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <?php while(have_posts()):the_post(); ?>
                                    <div style="padding: 5%; padding-left: 18%; padding-bottom: 0%; " id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"        
        <?php post_class("box-container"); ?>>    
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
             <?php endwhile; ?>
             <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

            </div>
            <!-- .row -->

        <!-- Page Content -->

        </div>
        <!-- .container -->

        <?php get_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: 'numberposts' and 'posts_per_page' can be used interchangeably.
I think you can not use both of them at a time.